# Convergence conditions of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Convergence conditions of:
$\displaystyle\sum \frac{\sin(x^n)}{(x+1)^n}$

What i did: $\sum \frac{\sin(x^n)}{(x+1)^n} < \sum \frac{x^n}{(x+1)^n}$

And after I studied with the root test when $\frac{|x|}{|x+1|} < 1$ but my solution (convergence for $x>-\frac{1}{2}$) isn't correct. Why? I cant do my increase?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for all real $x$, $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$. This stays the same after we replace $x$ with $x^n$...

Comment: And if $x\lt0$?

Comment: Considering this, when i study $|x|$ i have to consider only $0<x<1$ instead of $x>0$ but it seems not changing my solution and the correct one is $x>-\frac{1}{2}$ U $x<-2$